# VERP and perl postfix not working

Tags: perl, email, mime, postfix-mta, verp

So I have a script that I'm trying to get VERP running correctly on.  It's using MIME::Lite and postfix as the mail server.  Here is the code:

```
use strict;
use MIME::Lite;
use LWP::Simple;
use Mail::Verp;

my $email = 'someuser@somesite.com';
Mail::Verp->separator('+');
my $verp_email = Mail::Verp->encode('root@somesite.net', $email);
my $content = '<html><body>Hi!</body></html>';
my $msg = MIME::Lite->new(
    Subject => 'Hi',
    From => 'root@somesite.net',
    To => $email,
    'Return-Path' => $verp_email,
    Type => 'text/html',
    Data => $content
);
$msg->send('smtp', 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX');
```

When the message is bounced postfix isn't routing it to the root@somesite.net email inbox.  How do I route the message so that the sender of the bounce is the $verp_email value?

I'm trying to create a log of all bounced emails with the email addresses included so that it can then be sent to a file or a database.

If anyone can point me in the right direction with this I would be extremely appreciative.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: How do I make it bounce correctly?  The code as is does not seem to send the header information correctly.

Comment: "does not seem to" is just another version of "it doesn't work". If you want help, ask specific questions and include specific error messages and/or behaviour (or lack thereof).

Answer (score 0):

Return-Path is not the correct place for the VERP address, and will be ignored and/or overridden. You need to put it as the actual, honest to `$dmr`, real SMTP envelope sender (`MAIL FROM:<>`) address.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit old, but hopefully my answer will contribute to someone who find this while googling.
I had the same problem, and the root cause is that you must use "MAIL FROM: " during the smtp exchange with the target server.
Setting the return-path in the MIME::Header gets overwriten by the smtp server itself precisely based on the MAIL FROM smtp command.
So you can have a Mail envelope containing From: root@somesite.net but make sure the smtp MAIL FROM uses $verp_email
For example, this is what I have done:

```
my $msg = MIME::Entity->build(
    'Return-Path'   => 'bounce+user=user-domain.com@my-server.com',
    'From'      => 'admin@my-server.com',
    'To'        => 'user@user-domain.com',
    'Subject'   => $subject,
    'Errors-To' => 'bounce+user=user-domain.com@my-server.com'
);
## Then some more handling with MIME::Entity
## and finally send it over smtp

my @rcpt = $msg->smtpsend(
    ## Make it verbose for debugging
    'Debug'     => DEBUG,
    'Hello'     => 'mx1.my-server.com',
    'Host'      => 'mx.user-domain.com,
    'MailFrom'  => 'bounce+user=user-domain.com@my-server.com',
    'To'        => 'user@user-domain.com',
    'Port'      => 25,
);
```